# How to create ViewPager have item don't have ToolBar and TabLayout

Tags: android

I want to create a ViewPager that has 3 items. Items 1 and 2 contain a ToolBar and a TabLayout. Item 3 occupies the full screen. Please tell me how to do this. Thank you!!!

Comment: very simple, by when on item 3, make the tabLayout and toolBar view as gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes just find your Toolbar or TabLayout like that:

> tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

If you are calling that from a fragment :

> tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

Then to hide it:

> tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Same goes for your Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you want to only use tab icon for 2 item 0 and item 1. You need set tab.removeTabAt(3);